# C++ enum definitions not being accepted

Tags: c++, enums

I would like to use some `nss3.dll` code in my program. To do this I decided to declare all of the compound datatypes that it needs and call the functions inside the dll file with them.

I am using a file in the firefox source code to see how to properly use the functions I need. In one of the functions it declares one of these compound datatypes (`secuPWData`) and passes it variables. Here is the definition I pasted into my code without any errors:

```
typedef struct {
    enum {
        PW_NONE = 0,
        PW_FROMFILE = 1,
        PW_PLAINTEXT = 2,
        PW_EXTERNAL = 3
    } source;
    char *data;
} secuPWData;
```

The declaration of this struct looks like this in the code I'm looking at: `secuPWData  pwdata = { PW_NONE, NULL };`

When I try to use a similar (or even the same) declaration, it complains about the `PW_NONE` attribute, claiming it is undefined. When I tried to pass in the 0 value in its place, it told me that '*a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "enum secuPWData::"*'. To try to debug the issue, I tried pasting the definition right on top of the declaration, without any change.

What is causing this problem to occur?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try secuPWData::PW_NONE. Also remove the C tag.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that fixed it. What do you mean by the C tag?

Comment: A tag in the question.

Comment: @n.m. oh. I added that because the source file I was looking at was a .c file and not a .cpp file. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as @n.m. mentioned try using secuPWData::PW_NONE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct {
    enum {
        PW_NONE = 0,
        PW_FROMFILE = 1,
        PW_PLAINTEXT = 2,
        PW_EXTERNAL = 3
    } source;
    char *data;
} secuPWData;

int main() {
    secuPWData  pwdata = { secuPWData::PW_NONE, NULL };
    return 0;
}
```

worked for me .. [ideone - link](https://ideone.com/XpbVRH)